# Checking if every radiobutton is filled in before u submit a form in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I know that there are others posts with solutions on the site but i really need a clear view of what i am doing my form is the one below:

```
<form name="multichoice" action="">
    <table>
         <tr>
             <td>Q1.</td>
             <td>Do you think you are pretty?</td>
             <td class="radiobox"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1"/></td>
             <td class="radiobox"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="2"/></td>
             <td class="radiobox"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="3"/></td>
             <td class="radiobox"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="4"/></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
             <td>Q2.</td>
             <td>Do you think you are smart?</td>
             <td class="radiobox"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1"/></td>
             <td class="radiobox"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="2"/></td>
             <td class="radiobox"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="3"/></td>
             <td class="radiobox"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="4"/></td>
         </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

So i am looking for javascript code to make sure that every question will have an answer before we submit, looking forward for your answers

Thank you in advance if you can help

Comment: What have you tried? Which other questions have you found and read, what was lacking there?

Comment: Apparently you can only be smart or pretty, not both (the sets of radio buttons have the same name, needs to be different across questions), and you have to be smart to figure out what the unlabelled radio buttons mean. Ergo, anyone submitting the form claiming to be pretty is lying :p

Comment: What's wrong with the solutions you've found? Please ask for the things you don't understand, not for another solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay jQuery-free:

```
function isAnswered() {
  var radioGroups = {}
  for(i in (inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'))) {
    if(inputs[i].type === 'radio') {
      radioGroups[inputs[i].name] = radioGroups[inputs[i].name] ? true : inputs[i].checked;
    }
  }
  for(i in radioGroups) {
    if(radioGroups[i] === false) return false; 
  }
  return true;
}
```

This just iterates through each radio element, and keeps track of each radio group, looking for a "checked" value for each group. A similar solution in jQuery:

```
function isAnswered() {
  var isAnswered = true;
  $('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if($('input[name=' + $(this).attr('name') + ']:checked').length === 0) {
      isAnswered = false;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return isAnswered;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was better i understood it!

Comment: In which context? In the 3rd line of the first solution I am simply getting all of the `<input>` tags, and similarly in 3rd line of the second I am getting all of the `<input>` tags of type "radio". In the 5th line I am seeing if there is an `<input>` with the specified name that is also checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to achieve this, here is a sample to test :-

```
 if (!$("input[name='q1']:checked").val()) {

       return false;
    }
    if (!$("input[name='q2']:checked").val()) {     
       return false;
    }

    return;
```

if you wrap this inside a function and then call this function `onsubmit` event of the form. The validatio would be done.

EDIT:

Also there should be change in radio button names, each set or group of radiobuttons must have unique name. Like this :-

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <td>Q1.</td>
         <td>Do you think you are pretty?</td>
         <td class="radiobox"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1"/></td>
         <td class="radiobox"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="2"/></td>
         <td class="radiobox"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="3"/></td>
         <td class="radiobox"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="4"/></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
         <td>Q2.</td>
         <td>Do you think you are smart?</td>
         <td class="radiobox"><input type="radio" name="q2" value="1"/></td>
         <td class="radiobox"><input type="radio" name="q2" value="2"/></td>
         <td class="radiobox"><input type="radio" name="q2" value="3"/></td>
         <td class="radiobox"><input type="radio" name="q2" value="4"/></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so you are saying i should write this on a function like that

function CheckFill(){
    if (!$("input[name='q1']:checked").val()) {

       return false;
    }
    if (!$("input[name='q2']:checked").val()) {     
       return false;
    }

    return;
}

and on the html code
i will have:

<form name="multichoice" action="" onsubmit="checkFill()">

to run the function when i use the submit button?

Comment: yep perfect, just a small change. `<form name="multichoice" action="" onsubmit="return checkFill()">`